# Hibernate 5.2.9:@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql-9.4

I saw there are lot of questions asked earlier on the same thing in stack overflow in different ways. I looked at one of this issue on Hibernate forum and they mentioned it will work. We can refer this [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043630&view=previous)

Based on this link, lazy loading should work for basic properties type like byte[]

I am using hibernate version 5.2.9 + postgresql DB

My entity model looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ResourceFileEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;

@Column
private String storageType;

@Column
private String path;

@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column
byte[] fileContent;
// removed getters/setter for readibility
}
```

Code to fetch the entity is

```
public ResourceFileEntity fetchEntity(long jId) throws IOException {
Session session = factory.openSession();
ResourceFileEntity entity = null;
Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        entity = session.find(ResourceFileEntity.class, jId);
        System.out.println(Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(entity,      "fileContent" ));
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

A lot of folks have mentioned about bytecode enhancement, i did try that putting up all the required details in my project build.gradle and using @LazyGroup but still no luck.

Any input on this will be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you might be running into [HHH-10929](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10929). Although this has yet to be proven via a self-contained test case using the Hibernate [template](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates). It might be worth creating one if you think there is an issue?

Comment: +1. It could be a bug. If you like the JPA API better, then you can also use the [JPA test case template](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/).

Comment: Sure. Will add the test case. Thanks Vlad and Alex for the responses

Comment: I have added the test case in HHH-10929

Comment: Response on the Jira suggests you have an issue with your configuration. Does the suggested change solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it has...my entity was in src/test/java. It should be in src/main/java and in IDE somehow bytecode enhancement was not working. I run it through command line and its working. I am able to lazy load OneToOne and ManyToOne association also. Thanks for the help!